# Calling a Unity C# method that returns a value from Android/Java

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine, return-value

I am developing an Android plugin for Unity and I am wondering if there is a way in the Android code to call a Unity C# method that returns a value and get this value.

Of course this will NOT work but is there a way, tips, tricks to achieve something like this:

```
String myReturnedString = UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("MyGameObject", 
                          "ReturnThisString","hello");
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

**In Android:**

```
int Times_Called;
public  int Get_Times_Called()
{
   Times_Called += 1;
   return  Times_Called;
}
```

**In Unity**

```
 AndroidJavaClass Java = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
 AndroidJavaObject AndroidActivity = Java.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
 int Times_Called = AndroidActivity.Call<int>("Get_Times_Called");
        Debug.Log("Get_Times_Called: " + Times_Called);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to have a method in your Unity program that communicates with your Android application through a method in your Android app, by using *AndroidJavaObject.Call* in your Unity class.

e.g.
You have this method in your Android application.

**AndroidActivity.java**

```
String stringFromUnity = "";

public void setStringFromUnity(String input){
    stringFromUnity = input;
}
```

Then in your Unity script (I am using C#).

**UnityScript.cs**

```
// Get the UnityPlayer class
AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

// Get the current activity
AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

// Call the setStringFromUnity method from Android Activity
activity.Call("setStringFromUnity", "Here is a string for you, Android");
```

OR we can set the String directly using the *AndroidJavaObject.Set* method.

```
// Set the String directly provided the String is public
activity.Set<string>("stringFromUnity", "I set your String directly, hah!");
```

Hope this helps.

For reference, you can search for "Unity Plugins for Android" or take a look at Unity documentation at this [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html).

Answer (score 0):

First, we create a method 'reverse' in UnityPlayerActivity

*UnityPlayerActivity.java*:

```java
public class UnityPlayerActivity extends Activity {
    ...

    public String reverse(String str) {
        return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
    }
    ...
}
```

Then we call next block somewhere in Unity (e.g. in Monobehaviour):

```cs
private static void CallAndroidMethod()
{
    var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    var currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    var args = new object[1];
    args[0] = "Hello World!";
    var reversed = currentActivity.Call<string>("reverse", args);
    Debug.Log($"Reversed: {reversed}");
}
```

Finally, checking the Log (e.g. in AndroidStudio):

```
I/Unity: Reversed: !dlroW olleH
```

Comment: How can we return an array from Android to Unity? If our Android/Java function returns e.g. `List<String>` from a function called `getSensorsList`, what would the C#  look like? `var sensors = jo.Call<List<string>>("getSensorsList");` does not work.

Comment: How about this temporary solution (I need to investigate how to send a list) - convert a list of strings to a single string with some special divider between sensor values. Then parse it inside Unity.

Comment: @levgen Thanks, but I don't want a CSV string or something like that. It works with simple arrays, so I will use that for now.
`var sensornames = jo.Call<string[]>("getSensorList");`